# magento multilanguge sort order of store

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

I have multilanguage multistore magento. Below is my store switchers code. Where can I put sort or ksort to arrange stores by ID not name. As by default store is sorted by name and its not what i want.

```
<?php if(count($this->getGroups())>1): ?>
<div class="language-switcher" style="margin-left:15px">
    <label for="select-store"><?php echo $this->__('Select Store') ?>: </label>
    <select id="select-store" onchange="location.href=this.value">
    <?php /*foreach ($this->getStores() as $_store): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $_store->getUrl('') ?>"<?php if($_store->getId()==$this->getCurrentStoreId()): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $_store->getName() ?></option>
    <?php endforeach;*/ ?>
    <?php foreach ($this->getGroups() as $_group): ?>
        <?php $_selected = ($_group->getId()==$this->getCurrentGroupId()) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $_group->getHomeUrl() ?>" <?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_group->getName()) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to override following block:-

`Mage_Page_Block_Switch` ( file:- app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Switch.php )

There is function `getStores`, so you can rewrite this function as per your need in your class.

Comment: How can I rewrite? Plz Help

Comment: Here you can see how can we override a magento block, model etc. SO once you will able to override the above block then you will your own class where you can write the function with same name(getStores). So when your above template will call getStores then it will access your one only.


http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

Comment: Can you kindly rewrite it for me

Comment: I am trying for hours and no any result

Comment: Okay I will do it, but how can I give you the code, give me your mail id

Comment: The above code is saved store-top.phtml in my template
did you get my email?

Comment: Yes I got your email id and sent the code as well